# Android Developing: Is there a plugin or so for Eclipse , where a friend and i can develop at the same time?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a plugin or so for Eclipse, where a friend and i can develop at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

There are many plugins for source code version control (SVN, GIT, CVS), if that is what you are asking for. (Sorry if I misunderstood the question!)

I suggest you take a look at http://subclipse.tigris.org/ (SVN)!

(And if you need free SVN/GIT repositories: https://xp-dev.com/ or http://code.google.com)

Comment: thanks for your answer. When i use xp-dev. Is the source code closed? I don't want that anyone can see my source code except my friend.

Comment: xp-dev does offer free private repositories! Google doesn't! (As far as I know)